# Access tabs from dropdown menu in HTML

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, tabs

I have succeded to make a dropdown menu using HTML. The problem is I don't know how to move to a page from the dropdown menu. This is a piece of my code:

```
 <div class="dropdown">
                     <a href="#class="dropbtn"> Events</a>
                           <div class="dropdown-content">
                                   <a href="#"> Event1 </a>
                                   <a href="#"> Event2 </a>
                                   <a href="#"> Event3 </a>
                           </div> 
 </div>
```

I've tried using an id inside the div but it's not working.

Comment: add a link instead of # in <a href="">

Comment: `<a href="#class="dropbtn"> Events</a>` has a quote missing, might wanna edit that

Answer (score 0):

```
Try Like this: 

<div class="dropdown">
                     <a href="#class="dropbtn"> Events</a>
                           <div class="dropdown-content">
                                   <a href="https://www.google.co.in/"> Event1 </a>
                                   <a href="https://in.yahoo.com/
"> Event2 </a>
                                   <a href="http://www.rediff.com/"> Event3 </a>
                           </div> 
 </div>
```